# pow (x,y) in Java

Tags: java, math

What's the difference between:

```
Math.pow ( x,y ); // x^y
```

**To:**

```
x^y; // x^y
```

?

Will I prefer to use `x^y` with `double` type numbers? Or shell I have to use always with `Math.pow()` method?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise exclusive OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (XOR) operator in Java (and many other languages). It is not used for exponentiation. For that, you must use `Math.pow`.

Comment: So for example if I want to calc radius from (x,y), I need to: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2)) ; ???
thnx

Comment: @Master C: If you want to raise a number to a particular power, you want to use `Math.pow`.

Comment: @Master C: Besides that it's just the distance from the origin in 2d (there's no concept of a radius of a point), I think in this special case `Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)` is more readable.

Answer (score 12):

Additionally for what was said, if you want integer powers of two, then `1 << x` (or `1L << x`) is a faster way to calculate  2<sup>x</sup> than `Math.pow(2,x)` or a multiplication loop, and is guaranteed to give you an `int` (or `long`) result.

It only uses the lowest 5 (or 6) bits of `x` (i.e. `x & 31` (or `x & 63`)), though, shifting between 0 and 31 (or 63) bits.

Answer (score 5):

In Java `x ^ y` is an `XOR` operation.

Answer (score 4):

`x^y` is not "`x` to the power of `y`".  It's ["`x` XOR `y`"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operators#XOR).