# I want get the distance between two points but the output code is 0.0 for each values

Tags: java, android

I want get the distance between two points but the output code is 0.0 for each values.
I wrote the codes and it can run well. But the result of the output code is unreal and it displays 0.0

**Cal.java**

```
public class Cal extends View {
    Cal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public double result;
    double parameter = ((10-20)^2) + ((15-30)^2);
    public void cal(){
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cal = new Cal(this);
        textView.setText(""+ cal.result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up what `^` does.

Comment: you have to change your username !!

Comment: `Math.pow(x, y)` is what we use for `x ^ y`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to execute

```
cal.cal()
```

before using `cal.result` then result will be different from `0.0`

Comment: @UmaKanth `public void cal()` constructor?!

Comment: In fact the main problem is not from (^)

Comment: @developer implement calculation how Jordy says and then after you create object cal of type Cal, execute `cal.cal()` before you use `cal.result`

Comment: Thank you.Now it displays well.

Answer (score 1):

In java to make pow you must use [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)),

```
result = Math.pow((10-20),2)+Math.pow((15-30),2);
```

`^` is a [BitWise operator:](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).

> Binary XOR Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.   (A ^ B) will give 49 which is 0011 0001

Answer (score 0):

Look at [pow (x,y) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763652/pow-x-y-in-java)

Your code should be something like:
    ...

```
double parameter = (Math.pow((10-20),2)) + Math.pow((15-30),2));

...
```