# Random math generation algorithm not working

Tags: java, android, algorithm, random

Note that the question title is:

```
Random math question generation algorithm not working
```

because I can't enter "question" in question title...

---

So I am writing an android app that helps little kids learn maths by giving math questions to them. They can change the number of digits and the type of operation as they like. I am now confused with this algorithm that I wrote to generate random questions. It is generating the same question every time if with the same question options. For question options

```
number of digits: 1
operation: +
```

It is always 10 + 10.

Question options

```
number of digits: 2
operation: +
```

It is always 11 + 11.

Question options

```
number of digits: 3
operation: +
```

It is always 8 + 8.

Question options

```
number of digits: 2
operation: +
```

It is always 11 + 11.

Although the other operation types (-, +/-, *) are a bit more random, one of its operands is always the same. 1 digit is 10, 2 digits is 11, 3 digits is 8.

Now here is my algorithm:

```
public void generateAQuestion () {
    switch (options.getOperationType ()) {
        case ADDITION:
            current = generateAddition ();
            break;
        case SUBTRACTION:
            current = generateSubtraction ();
            break;
        case ADD_AND_SUB:
            current = generateAddAndSub ();
            break;
        case MULTIPLICATION:
            current = generateMultiplication ();;
            break;
    }
}

private int generateNumberWithDigitCount () {
    int minValue = 10 ^ (options.getDigitCount () - 1);
    int maxValue = 10 ^ options.getDigitCount () - 1;
    Random r = new Random ();
    return r.nextInt (maxValue - minValue + 1) + minValue;
}

private Question generateAddition () {
    int operand1, operand2;
    operand1 = generateNumberWithDigitCount ();
    operand2 = generateNumberWithDigitCount ();
    return new Question (operand1, operand2);
}

private Question generateSubtraction () {
    int operand1 = generateNumberWithDigitCount ();
    Random r = new Random ();
    int operand2 = -(r.nextInt (operand1));
    return new Question (operand1, operand2);
}

private Question generateAddAndSub () {
    Question firstPart;
    if (Math.random () > 0.5) {
        firstPart = generateAddition ();
    } else {
        firstPart = generateSubtraction ();
    }
    int[] operands = new int[3];
    operands[0] = firstPart.getOperands ()[0];
    operands[1] = firstPart.getOperands ()[1];

    if (Math.random () > 0.5) {
        Random r = new Random ();
        operands[2] = -(r.nextInt (firstPart.getAnswer ()));
    } else {
        operands[2] = generateNumberWithDigitCount ();
    }

    return new Question (operands);
}

private MultiplicationQuestion generateMultiplication () {
    return new MultiplicationQuestion (generateNumberWithDigitCount (), generateNumberWithDigitCount ());
}

private int[] generateAnswers (int correctAnswer) {
    int[] answers = new int[4];
    Random r = new Random ();
    int correctAnswerIndex = r.nextInt (4);
    answers[correctAnswerIndex] = correctAnswer;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < answers.length ; i++) {
        if (i == correctAnswerIndex) {
            continue;
        }

        if (Math.random () > 0.5) {
            answers[i] = correctAnswer + (i + 1);
        } else {
            int candidate = correctAnswer - (i + 1);
            if (candidate < 0) {
                candidate = correctAnswer + i + 5;
            }
            answers[i] = candidate;
        }
    }
    return answers;
}
```

Notes: `options` is the question options, its methods are self explanatory, you can get it.Don't care about the `Question` and `MultiplicationQuestion`'s constructors, they are irrelevant.

And I don't know what I did wrong, everything makes sense to me. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: So change the title to "random math *problem* generation . . ."

Comment: @JimMischel the word "question" is not allowed on question titles

Comment: I realize that. I suggested using the word *problem* in place of *question*.

Comment: @JimMischel problem is also not allowed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is wrong here is where you use 10 ^  options.get...
that isnt the same as power, you can in turn use Math.pow(10, options.get...)

The problem you have is that the ^ operator does not act as a exponent mod in this case :)

edited code

```
int minValue = (int)(Math.pow(10, (options.getDigitCount () - 1));
int maxValue = (int)(Math.pow(10, options.getDigitCount ())-1;
```

I completely understand why you got this wrong, as it is taught in many math classes that the ^ symbol means power

Comment: Wait I thought there is exponent in java... Is ^ from another language or something? Am I using C# again?

Comment: might be for C#, but as Henry said, it is the XOR operator for java

Comment: `^` means exponentiation in most dialects of Basic

Comment: glad to help, great idea for a program btw sweeper

Comment: This is a good answer (plus one) but do be sure not to initialise the generator more than once.

Comment: @Sweeper `^` is the xor operator in most (all?) C-based languages http://stackoverflow.com/q/5763652/995714

Answer (score 3):

`Random r = new Random ();` re-initialises the generator.

Do that once, not each time you need a number. Otherwise you ruin the statistical properties of the generator.

Then separate the `minValue` and `maxValue` values to have different values, currently they are equal, and probably meaningless due to the misuse of the XOR operator `^`.

Comment: `new Random()` should use a seed that is unlikely to have been used in past instantiations, according to the doc...

Comment: It still completely ruins the generator's statistical properties.

Comment: I agree. I was going to point it out in the comments, but I feel like it is not by itself an answer to the question. The point about min and max is more likely to be the root cause.

Comment: I cite both. But I think misuse of random generators is *far* worse. (And @TDG spotted that before I did ;-))

Comment: @Bathsheba, "You ruin the statistical properties". Why? The chances of `nextInt(2)` returning 1 will always be 50%.

Comment: Rubbish. I've studied this extensively and I am correct. Google for more details.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is the XOR operator in Java. Given that, your expressions for max and min value do not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `^` is not for taking the power but for exclusive bitwise or.

Have a field:

```
private Random rand = new Random();

private int generateNumberWithDigitCount () {
    int pow10max = 1;
    for (int digits = options.getDigitCount(); digits > 0; --digits) {
        pow10max *= 10;
    }
    int pow10min = pow10max / 10;
    return pow10min - rand.nextInt(pow10max - pow10min);
}
```